# Writing data to file but file still contain NULL

Tags: c, encryption, file-handling

Related to my previous post but its not a duplicate of that.Now I have tried something and

Here I am asking you about the logical error in code.

```
/*u_int8_t ....etc are alias for uint8_t...etc so don't bother about them*/

void crypt(u_int8_t *key, u_int32_t keylen,
    u_int8_t *data, u_int32_t datalen)
{
    FILE *fp,*fq;

    fp=fopen("key","w");
    fputs((char *)key,fp);
    fq=fopen("file.txt","w");
    d=0;
    while(data[d]) {
        fputc((int)data[d],fq);
        d++;
    }
    fputc('\0',fq);

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fq)
}
```

Output :

```
udit@udit-Dabba ~/Downloads/sendip-2.5-mec-2/mec $ cat key 
kaheudit@udit-Dabba ~/Downloads/sendip-2.5-mec-2/mec $ cat file.txt 
udit@udit-Dabba ~/Downloads/sendip-2.5-mec-2/mec $
```

Key gets printed to file but not the data.

Now when I slightly modify the code :

```
void
crypt(u_int8_t *key, u_int32_t keylen,
    u_int8_t *data, u_int32_t datalen)
{

    int d,k;
    FILE *fp,*fq;

    fp=fopen("key","w");
    fputs((char *)key,fp);

    fq=fopen("file.txt","w");
    for (d=0, k=0; d < datalen; ++d, k = (k+1)%keylen) {
          data[d] ^= key[k];
          fputc(data[d],fq);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fq);

}
```

Now key as well as data gets printed...although data is not exactly correct(but it is able to be written down into the file)

```
udit@udit-Dabba ~/Downloads/sendip-2.5-mec-2/mec $ cat key 
kaheudit@udit-Dabba ~/Downloads/sendip-2.5-mec-2/mec $ cat file.txt 
kthpOWWkahe;c��"�he
kajcudit@udit-Dabba ~/Downloads/sendip-2.5-mec-2/mec $
```

The call to the crypt function is as follows -

```
  bool
  espcrypto(esp_private *epriv, sendip_data *data, sendip_data *pack)
  {
      u_int32_t keylen;
      u_int8_t *key;
      static u_int8_t fakekey;
      struct ip_esp_hdr *esp = (struct ip_esp_hdr *)pack->data;

      if (!epriv->keylen) {   /* This isn't going to be very productive... */
          key = &fakekey;
          keylen = 1;
      } else {
          key = (u_int8_t *)epriv->key;
          keylen = epriv->keylen;
      }

      /* Encrypt everything past the ESP header */
      crypt(key, keylen,
            (u_int8_t *)esp->enc_data,
             pack->alloc_len + data->alloc_len 
                 - sizeof(struct ip_esp_hdr));
      return TRUE;
  }
```

The following packet describe what data I actually need to write down to the file...

```
udit@udit-Dabba ~/Downloads/sendip-2.5-mec-2/mec $ sendip -v -p ipv6 -dabcd -6s ::1 -p    
esp -es 0x20 -eq 0x40 -ek "kahe" -ec crypt.so -p tcp -ts 21 -td 21 ::2

Added 43 options
Initializing module ipv6
Initializing module esp
Initializing module tcp
Finalizing module tcp
Finalizing module esp
Finalizing module ipv6
Final packet data:
60 00 00 00   `...
00 24 32 20   .$2 
00 00 00 00   ....
00 00 00 00   ....
00 00 00 00   ....
00 00 00 01   ....
00 00 00 00   ....
00 00 00 00   ....
00 00 00 00   ....
00 00 00 02   ....
00 00 00 20   ... 
00 00 00 40   ...@
6B 74 68 70   kthp  /*data portion starts from here*/
4F 57 1F 57   OW.W
6B 61 68 65   kahe
3B 63 97 9A   ;c..
22 C0 68 65   ".he
0A 03 0B 01   ....
6B 61 6A 63   kajc  /*data portion ends here*/
Freeing module ipv6
Freeing module esp
Freeing module tcp
```

Please help me.... I haven't receiver any satisfactory implementation on my previous post   still so trying my own hand.Really need it ..

Comment: You should be `fclose`-ing those files, which should probably be opened in binary mode "wb".

Comment: It might be easier to spot what's going on if you temporarily put some printf() calls in to show what e.g. data[d], and key[k] are, before you ^= and fputs() it to file.txt

Comment: @K-ballo sorry forgot to write here in code but now i have edited.I am already closing both the files in both situation.

Comment: Why are there parameters named datalen and keylen if you assume data and key are null-terminated?

Comment: Is this C or C++? It looks like C, but you've tagged it with both languages...

Comment: @Sii actually it is a pre-defined implemented xor encryption module which I need to change ... so could not change the name and parameters of function but yes working can be changed.So actual task is to  implement AES through openssl.Also that null is not must that is only my thinking may be I am wrong !!! I did this to avoid  any memory-leakage .... If I am wrong correct me on that .

Comment: @Cameron I have tagged it with both languages because I have no problem in using c++ if any implementation suggested in that.

Comment: @mamir tried using print statements `printf("%s",key);` prints the key but `printf("%s",data);` prints nothing.

Comment: @Udit Gupta sorry I removed the C++ tag since the question only mention C methods.

Comment: Are you calling the `crypt` function on encrypted, or unencrypted data when it doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using string semantics to handle binary data. That's not going to work. If you look closely you'll see that the first character in your file.txt example output is `k`, which is also the first character of the key. That means your data is starting with a NUL byte and the while loop will instantly exit.

First of all you need to open the files in binary mode:

```
fp=fopen("key","wb");
fq=fopen("file.txt","wb");
```

To write the key use

```
fwrite(key, keylen, 1, fp);
```

and then use the for loop in your second example to write the data. I can't see anything wrong with that one, your problem might simply have been the binary vs text mode.

Edit: Try using `hexdump -C file.txt` to view your file instead of cat.

Comment: The part about the null byte is probably his problem.  The part about `fopen` probably isn't relevant (aside from portability) though, since it looks like he's on a Linux or Unix system and `"wb"` and `"w"` are probably equivalent in this case.

Comment: Maybe. He does have a `0A` in the encrypted output though.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
while(data[d]) {
    fputc((int)data[d],fq);
    d++;
}
```

data[d] is 0 (as it is binary data), so it will leave the loop "too" soon.